# How to get Azure AD authentication to work in production with msal-browser in my Next.js application?

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication, next.js, azure-ad-msal

The following implementation of msal works without issues when I run it on localhost. But when I deploy it to an Azure App Service the clientId and/or tenantID seems to become undefined, even when I tried experimenting with placing the id strings directly into the file. Here is the error I get when i try to click the login button in production:

`GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/undefined/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration 400 (Bad Request)`

```
Uncaught (in promise) ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints. Check your authority and verify the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns the required endpoints. Attempted to retrieve endpoints from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/undefined/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
    at t [as constructor] (_app-3866deb516d5bf6f9628.js:1)
    at new t (_app-3866deb516d5bf6f9628.js:1)
    at Function.t.createEndpointDiscoveryIncompleteError (_app-3866deb516d5bf6f9628.js:1)
    at Function.<anonymous> (_app-3866deb516d5bf6f9628.js:1)
    at _app-3866deb516d5bf6f9628.js:1
    at Object.throw (_app-3866deb516d5bf6f9628.js:1)
    at s (_app-3866deb516d5bf6f9628.js:1)
```

And here is the msal implementation:

```
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";

function redirUri() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
        return "/"
    } else {
        return "https://somewebsitename.azurewebsites.net/"
    }
}

const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID}`,
        redirectUri: redirUri()
    }
};

const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

export { msalInstance }
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the app setting in Azure app service configuration.
You can get the ClientID and tenant Id from your application configuration by doing this.
process.env.clientId and process.env.tenantId

Ensure you have configured the following settings on the portal:

[image]

[image]